# How to trigger button with html href?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code in my HTML/CSS/Div table, and the href works without issue.  Is it possible to replace the href code such that when this image is clicked, instead of opening the URL, a button click is activated?

Working Code

```html
<a class="test-link" href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
  <img class="testgrey" src="./grey.svg" />
  <img class="test-white" src="./white.svg" />
</a>
```

Desired Outcome from clicking on the image defined above:
this button gets activated without actually placing the button on the html page:

```html
<a class="button button--small card-figcaption-button quickview" tabindex="0" data-product-id="113">Buy</a>
```

Comment: How do you _"activate"_ something that isn't _"on the html page"_? And what does _"activate"_ mean in this context?

Comment: You can add a click handler to your anchor that delegates a click event to the button.

Comment: You can use a button instead use onclick

Comment: If the page simply contained the button, then by clicking the button some code gets executed, and that button works without issue.  So wondering if it's possible that the image defined in the a-class code somehow triggers this button instead of opening the URL defined in the href.

Comment: well, why you need to trigger a button. you can just attach an event listener for the <a> element and on click just execute your code. just use event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() on click, and then the click won't trigger navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a click handler to your anchor that delegates a click event to the button.

```js
// Delagate the link click to the button click
document.querySelector('#my-link').addEventListener('click', e =>
  document.querySelector('#my-button').click());

// Handle button clicks
document.querySelector('#my-button').addEventListener('click', e =>
  console.log('button click...'));
```

```html
<a id="my-link" href="#">Click Me</a><br><br>
<button id="my-button">I will be clicked programatically</button>
```

Comment: Well, that "actually plac[es] the button on the html page"...

Comment: correct, I don't want the button placed on the html page,so I guess without placing the button on the html page it's not possible that the code behind the actual button gets executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener directly to the `<a>` element and call the button handler;

```
document.querySelector('.test-link').addEventListener('click', function(event){
   //prevent navigation
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();

   // call your button handler directly
   callButtonEventHandler();

   return false;
});
```

You can't trigger a button click without a button on the page.
You can only call it's handler if it's available in javascript.

Comment: How can I expose its handler? (newbie here)

Comment: can I trigger a button click if the button exists on a different html page?

Comment: no, you can't trigger a button from a different page. every page has specific resources, meaning javascript/html/css

Comment: The handler is the javascript function that executes when an event is triggered.
```...addEventListener([event], [eventHandler])```.
That button you want to trigger I guess it has its own handler, that you want to execute. So you can call that handler directly, if you have access to it.

Comment: so if you have somewhere in javascript:
`[theOtherButton].addEventListener([event], buttonEventHandler)`
where `buttonEventHandler` is the function that executes the code for the other button.
you can do 

`document.querySelector('.test-link').addEventListener('click', function(event){
   //prevent navigation
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();

   // call your button handler directly
   buttonEventHandler();

   return false;
});`